# Can i setup Angular 6 without using/installing node.js/npm?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I know there is an easy solution with Angular CLI but is it possible to setup and run an Angular app without installing Node.js or running npm commands in the terminal.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That is simply not possible. In angular you have to use many of npm modules and node itself as the development server

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by not wanting to use Node and NPM?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to/have to do this?

Comment: angular 6 is not having any dependency then why its not possible

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. I just had a necessity to have it installed without those. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. Angular has a complicated build process that isn't realistically doable without having Node installed. If you really can't/won't install NodeJS, perhaps try an online IDE such as [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your response @UncleDave.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's impossible to build an app with Angular and without Node if you want to use Local IDE like VSCode

It's not recommended for sure. the best alternative way is to use yarn + Angular CLI.

You can use Online IDE if you won't install node and npm on your machine. (http://stackblitz.com)

Yarn is an alternative package manager for npm, so you can use it.

**Update to use Yarn with Angular CLI**

```
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

and to revert this change :

```
ng set --global packageManager=npm
```

Comment: This won't work as yarn depends on node. So you'd have to install Node.js anyway which comes with npm

Comment: in question he is asking without terminal

Comment: Yes you are right. By the way, it's impossible and I propose the best alternate way to use npm as less as possible